# What standard, if any, defines HTMLDocument.style?

Tags: css, dom, standards

Mozilla's web docs define the [HTMLElement.style](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style) property.

My (most likely wrong) understanding is that such properties should be defined in the [DOM standard](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/). However, I cannot find it.

So, my question is: what standard, if any, defines `HTMLElement.style`?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style#Specification…?

Comment: https://drafts.csswg.org/cssom/#dom-elementcssinlinestyle-style

Comment: I guess I was confused because I didn't know that there were *mix-ins* that augment the interfaces of DOM elements.